# Implementing createMatchMedia() for material-ui. I'm using a material ui hidden component to hide buttons while I'm trying to test them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm using React-testing-library getByText to find a button that's hidden by a material ui component called Hidden. Since RTL won't find it, Material ui has an implementation of it here https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#testing. But I can't figure out how to implement it to simply to find a button. The button is located once I remove Hidden, I am just not sure how to use their createMatchMedia() for a query within my test.

The Hidden component hides my button at 959px and down .

```
import React from "react"
import { render } from '../../../../test/test-utils'
import Collections from "./Collections"
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import mediaQuery from 'css-mediaquery'

function createMatchMedia(width: any) {
  return (query: string): any => ({
    matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
    addListener: () => {},
    removeListener: () => {},
  });
}

type CollectionsProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Collections>

const baseProps: CollectionsProps = {
  setValue: () => {},
  setSelectedIndex: () => {},
  pageStyle: {},
  pageAnimations: {transition : {}, variants: {}},
  motions: {animate:'', initial: '', exit: ''},
  jumpTo: (jumpingTarget: string | number | Element): void => {}
}

const renderUI = (props: Partial<CollectionsProps>) =>
     render(<Collections {...baseProps} {...props} />, {}) 

describe('When a filter is clicked', () => {

  beforeAll( () => {
    window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(window.innerWidth)
  })

  let { getByText } = renderUI({})

    test('items shown are only related to the picked Category', () => {
      userEvent.click(getByText(/Team Colors/))
    })  
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTL is not the problem here. The problem is in [jsdom](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#testing) which doesn't have an implementation of `matchMedia()`. Jest uses jsdom internally and without an existing `matchMedia()` no media query will match in Material UI's [Hidden API](https://material-ui.com/api/hidden/).

1. You may solve this by first installing NPM packages [css-mediaquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-mediaquery) and [@types/css-mediaquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/css-mediaquery).
2. Then create a mock for `matchMedia` like so:

```
// matchMedia.mock.ts
export const createMatchMedia = (width: number) => (query: string): MediaQueryList => ({
  matches: mediaQuery.match(query, { width }),
  media: query,
  onchange: null,
  addListener: () => jest.fn(),
  removeListener: () => jest.fn(),
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
  dispatchEvent: jest.fn()
});

window.matchMedia = createMatchMedia(window.innerWidth);

export default {};
```

3. Import the mock file above in `setupTest.ts` (your Jest test setup file) like so:

```
// setupTests.ts
import './__mocks__/matchMedia.mock';
...
```

4. Write your test as you normally would. No need to use the `beforeAll()` to create a new `window.matchMedia`. The mock file takes care of that for you.